# Opencv --- I cannot use the function imread

Tags: opencv

I have a problem in opencv function. I can use

```
IplImage* img = CvLoadImage("2_DeepViewOutput.png");
```

However I cannot use

```
Mat img = imread("2_DeepViewOutput.png");
```

It gave me

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Line breakpoint: Hello.cpp [line: 11]
>     - undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string     const&, int)'

I think I have loaded the library in the path. I did not know the reason, please help me.

Comment: Windows? Compiler clearly says you have not linked with the proper lib (probably opencv2's `highgui`).

Comment: possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770115/linking-libraries-opencv-2-4-2-on-xcode-4-5-1), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584273/issue-with-reading-an-image-using-cvimread-function-in-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have included C header files, not C++ header files. So, your program cannot be compiled because the declaration of the cv::imread(std::string const&, int) function is not present in the C header file.

So, you have to include C++ header files. (e.g - #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp") (This [link](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/06/load-display-image.html) will help you)

And if you have not configured your IDE for C++, please go through this [link](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the missing dll in your IDE path. Following this [link](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html) step by step will solve your issue.

Comment: I think I am right in IDE path, if I was wrong, how can I run the function CVLoadImage ? Is it C++ function can not run? C is OK?

Comment: No,I using elcipse, opencv 2.4.5. Now, I have to programming by C, because I cannot use C++ function in opencv. Like I can use CvLoadImage to load an image, I cannot use imread directly.

Comment: No there is something wrong, can you try with Netbeans? ITs pretty straight forward.

Comment: I am familiar with eclipse... I still have no idea on that.