# g++ ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc

I'm trying to compile the Sam Hare's [Struck code](http://www.samhare.net/research/struck/code).

I'm using mac OSX10.9, opencv 2.4.6 and Eigen 2.0.17.

Eigen and opencv headers are stored in /opt/local/include while opencv dylib in /opt/local/lib.

I modified the Hare's Makefile to work on this folder. When I type make on the terminal:

```
g++ -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc src/Config.o src/Features.o src/HaarFeature.o src/HaarFeatures.o src/HistogramFeatures.o src/ImageRep.o src/LaRank.o src/MultiFeatures.o src/RawFeatures.o src/Sampler.o src/Tracker.o src/main.o src/GraphUtils/GraphUtils.o -o struck
```

I get these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
"cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,
int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o   "cv::split(cv::Mat const&, std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&)",
referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o   "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,
int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o   "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,
cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      LaRank::Debug() in LaRank.o
      Tracker::Debug() in Tracker.o
      _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You have a conflict between 32bit and 64bit libraries.

Comment: Ok, actually I have no idea how to solve it. Any hint?

Comment: You need to check all the libraries you linking together, whether they are 32 or 64 bits. I don't know how to do it if you are not sure where you get them.

Answer (score 47):

I had a similar warning/error/failure when I was simply trying to make an executable from two different object files (main.o and add.o). I was using the command:

`gcc -o exec main.o add.o`

But my program is a C++ program. Using the `g++` compiler solved my issue:

`g++ -o exec main.o add.o`

I was always under the impression that `gcc` could figure these things out on its own. Apparently not. I hope this helps someone else searching for this error.

Comment: Me too was assuming just that: "I was always under the impression that gcc could figure these things out on its own."

Answer (score 9):

finally solved my problem.

I created a new project in XCode with the sources and changed the C++ Standard Library from the default libc++ to libstdc++ as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770115/linking-libraries-opencv-2-4-2-on-xcode-4-5-1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637164/c-linking-error-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-10-9-xcode-5-0-1).

Comment: In my case, adding 'libc++.dylib' to Frameworks resolved the issue. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

When I using `clang` to compile a C++ program, I have the similar error.

But after I changing to use `chang++`, the compilation worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30844320)

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same error.  I don't think it is a "fix", but my work-around is to also include the cpp file.  So instead of just putting

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

I have to put

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "MyClass.cpp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my declarition in the .h file

```
class String
{
    String (const char * cstr = 0);
};
```

and I used inline in another .cpp file (implementation)

```
inline String::String(const char * cstr)
{
//code ... 
}
```

then I use g++ and get this:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"String::String(char const*)", referenced from:
_main in test-d389f3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

solution: do not write **inline** when declarition and implementation is independent.