# Xcode - C++ libstdc++ Thread file not found - C++11 enabled

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, libstdc++

I have a program that I need to compile using `libstdc++` but I am getting a compilation error stating `thread file not found`.

I have added `C++11` in the language dialect option for the LLVM compiler but I am still getting the error that the `thread file is not found`.

Does anything additional need to be added to the linker flags for thread support?

Comment: Why do you need to use `libstdc++` instead of the standard `libc++`? And how did you set it up to use the GCC library and its header files?

Comment: Due to errors I get when compiling the code, this question has the same problem I have. The given solution was to try using `libstdc++`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821041/g-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: Could you give more information to setting Xcode up to use the GCC library and header files?