# Problems linking FFTW with gfortran (symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64)

Tags: gfortran, fftw

I am on macOS Catalina (10.15.5) and I have installed FFTW using `brew install fftw`. I also have GCC (version 10.2.0) installed which is symlinked to the commands I am using below.

I am able to compile and run a simple C++ program like so:

```
g++-10 test.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lfftw3 -lm
```

But, I had to modify the environment variable `CPATH` to make this work.

I am unable to get a simple Fortran FFTW example to work (I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/appleparan/c048c44668ede7ef28ba63c660b6dcf3) one). The command I am using to compile is:

```
gfortran-10 test.f90 -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lfftw3 -lm
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__gfortran_os_error_at", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccRvJaEQ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I understand correctly, the linking step fails. Any inputs on how I might find the relevant paths that I may have to pass to the compiler would be very helpful. I searched for solutions and I wasn't able to find one. But, in case I missed something obvious, I apologise.

Comment: Do you have fftw3 Fortran library installed? I am not mac user so do not know the technical stuff, but at least usually the libraries have to be language specific. In my mind, one cannot use library meant for C or C++ for Fortran...

Comment: @msi_gerva Good point, but yes, FFTW functions can be called from Fortran and I have the required files. I think that's why the compiling step doesn't seem to have caused any problems. So, I think that's not the issue here.

Comment: Perhaps you can try with your own installed version - http://www.fftw.org/download.html? To make sure that the library is built with the same version of compiler...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: @msi_gerva I compiled FFTW on my own, but the issue persists!

Comment: For me everything works, I was able also to run command (compile your testcase): `gfortran -o test.x test.f90 -L/nobackup/opt/gfortran/9.3.0/fftw-install_3.3.8/lib -I/nobackup/opt/gfortran/9.3.0/fftw-install_3.3.8/include -lfftw3 -lm`  . The /nobackup/... was the location, where I installed the library. In addition, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821041/g-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64. Is it possible that you are mixing 32bit and 64bit libraries?

Comment: I compiled FFTW to a custom directory now, and the compilation for the Fortran test case works. Perhaps I need to remove past instances of FFTW files in the default paths to avoid possible mixing up 32bit and 64bit libraries? Thanks for your help @msi_gerva!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [msi_gerva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913367/msi-gerva)'s helpful hints through comments, I was able to solve the issue by downloading [FFTW](http://fftw.org/download.html) and compiling it to a custom directory following the [installation directions](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-Unix.html#Installation-on-Unix).

Now, the linking doesn't fail if I pass the new locations of the libraries to `gfortran` like so:

```
gfortran-10 test.f90 -L/new/path/to/lib -I/new/path/to/include -lfftw3 -lm
```

Since `/usr/local/` is the default installation path, it's possible that there is a mixing up of the FFTW library files from previous installations.