# Building opencv example in OS X 10.8 with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, opencv

I'm trying to build the following example using Eclipse in OS X 10.8:

```
//============================================================================

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

but getting this result:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project cvTesting ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/cvTesting.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include/opencv2 -I/opt/local/include/opencv2/core/ -        I/opt/local/include/opencv2/highgui/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/cvTesting.d"     -MT"src/cvTesting.d" -o "src/cvTesting.o" "../src/cvTesting.cpp"
../src/cvTesting.cpp:9:33: warning: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
../src/cvTesting.cpp:10:39: warning: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
../src/cvTesting.cpp:13: error: 'cv' is not a namespace-name
../src/cvTesting.cpp:13: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
../src/cvTesting.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
../src/cvTesting.cpp:24: error: 'Mat' was not declared in this scope
../src/cvTesting.cpp:24: error: expected `;' before 'image'
../src/cvTesting.cpp:25: error: 'image' was not declared in this scope
../src/cvTesting.cpp:25: error: 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR' was not declared in this scope
../src/cvTesting.cpp:25: error: 'imread' was not declared in this scope
../src/cvTesting.cpp:33: error: 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE' was not declared in this scope
../src/cvTesting.cpp:33: error: 'namedWindow' was not declared in this scope
../src/cvTesting.cpp:34: error: 'imshow' was not declared in this scope
../src/cvTesting.cpp:36: error: 'waitKey' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [src/cvTesting.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

I have opencv installed such that pkg-config reports the following:

$ pkg-config opencv --cflags

-I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include

and

$ pkg-config --libs opencv

/opt/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib         /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_ml.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_photo.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_ts.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_video.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.dylib

and within Eclipse, in the project properties I have, C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler "All options" set to:

-I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include/opencv2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0

and the C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MacOS X C++ Linker -> "All options" is set to:
-L/opt/local/lib

I also have the following libraries (-l) listed in C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MacOS X C++ Linker -> Libraries:

opencv_core
opencv_imgproc
opencv_highgui
opencv_ml
opencv_video
opencv_features2d
opencv_calib3d
opencv_objdetect
opencv_contrib
opencv_legacy
opencv_flann

I am able to build this same example in Ubuntu, just not OS X.  Can anyone help explain the setup for the paths used by eclipse in OS X, for opencv?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the compiler output:

> ../src/cvTesting.cpp:9:33: warning: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
>   ../src/cvTesting.cpp:10:39: warning: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory

Eclipse can't find core.hpp and highgui.hpp files. Are you sure that those files are in these locations?

Also you may try to use `core.h` and `highgui.h` instead of `*.hpp` files.

Comment: The core.hpp and highgui.hpp files are in the correct locations, which is

/opt/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp
/opt/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp

however this isn't searched when using the preprocessor syntax: 

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

Comment: I didn't try, but I'm pretty sure I could build it by providing the specific path to these include files.  However, the build environment
needs to be able to resolve references to <opencv2/...>

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more more research on the topic, and working through various options, I found the best approach to be using Xcode rather than Eclipse for the IDE while in OS X.

The information I used to get Xcode setup and working correctly is in the Answer posted here:

[Compile OpenCV (2.3.1+) for OS X Lion / Mountain Lion with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552839/compile-opencv-2-3-1-for-os-x-lion-mountain-lion-with-xcode)

Prior to doing this though, I went back through the Mac OS X OpenCV Port instructions found here:
   http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port

Hope this helps others trying to use OpenCV with a modern IDE in OS X...

-Walt