# Which version of OpenCV should I use?

Tags: macos, opencv

I'm running Mac OSX Mavericks (10.9) w/ the latest Xcode (5.0.2) and command line tools installed.

Which, if any, version of OpenCV is the best bet for avoiding build and/or compile errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go with the current release 2.4.7. The sources can be downloaded from the official [opencv page](http://opencv.org/). On OSX, you can use also MacPorts to install precompiled OpenCV libraries as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8559953/2631225).

Personally, I build OpenCV without installing it to the system libraries. Instead, I'm pointing in my project just to the OpenCV build directory. That's very easy with cmake.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll give that a try.  I didn't have luck with 2.4.7 using cmake/gcc, then tried 2.4.6.1 b/c I read it worked better with OSX 10.9, but still no luck.  I don't think I need the latest version, so just wondering if there's a past version that is easier to get working with the latest OSX.

Comment: What do you mean with **still no luck**? Maybe you should clarify in your question at which step you had problems. If you have problems building OpenCV, then there is something wrong with your build system (usually cmake gives helpful output). If OpenCV could be built but your application NOT, there is something wrong in your makefile, cmake or xcode project-file.

Comment: Perhaps I'll do that in a new question.  The question I was asking though, is if there's a specific version of OpenCV that tends to work work better with MacOSX. That is all.  It wasn't the right question to ask on SO.  No biggie.  Thanks for your answer!