# Integrating opencv with xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, opencv

I am working on an iOS app based on image processing and would like to use **OpenCV** library. The documentation given on opencv.org is pretty old. I would like to code in swift, so how should I integrate the library with my app?

Comment: Just for info: looking at the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/opencv/info), it looks like one answer is [still relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8559953/2227743) (the `brew` part) except for point 7 (I guess for Swift you would have to make a bridging header instead).

Comment: What I have done at work for a similar situation is take the C++ library, in this case OpenCV, and integrate it into some Objective-C++ code. Build a library for it with an Objective-C interface and then drag and drop the library and a bridge file into your swift project and you should be good to go

Comment: I have tried linking the openCV framework but I am getting the error PrefixHeader.pch:15:9: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found @choward